# Querying : redis or mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, performance, redis, nosql

I want to set up a notification system.
They would look something like this :

```
{user_id: 1, type: 'comment', content: [msg: 'bluhbluh', date: '2014-01-01']}
{user_id: 1, type: 'message', content: [msg: 'blahblah', date: '2014-01-01']}
```

I would need to query on user_id AND type. I know it is easily do-able with mongoDB. From what I found on the Internet, it is not so easy with Redis since it only works with key/value.

Do you know if there is a way to achieve this with Redis, and if it has better performance than mongoDB.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it is easier to set up a notification system using pub-sub architecture and you have many choices on how to do it. One fast and simple option is using [zeromq pub-sub pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Getting-the-Message-Out) and of course you have many other choices.

Now redis vs mongodb would mainly depend on how durable you want the data to be and how complex of a query engine are you looking for. If the notifications are mostly stored in memory and consumed fast enough then redis is a good solution. You can work around key-value limitation by constructing concatenated keys (ex:type.user_id) and doing some sort of prefix searches on sorted sets. Mongodb would be better if you want the data to be persistent and expect complex query model in future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I probably didn't use the right term when I said notification. I wasn't talking about phone notications, but more like the ones on Facebook when you have a new message. I'm gonna go for Redis !

Answer (score 1):

The best solution will depend upon how the queue is filled and consumed along with how durable the messages need to be.

Redis supports pub/sub, which could be useful if you're pushing notifcations to workers. This would keep you from needing to query your datastore alltogether.

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Another option for the worker scenario is rabbitmq. This approach might save you some time writing queue/worker infrastrcutre.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/